# What does the lock next to the include directory mean?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 7.2.1 for Ubuntu Quantal Quetzal to program C++. Unfortunately, its code assistance doesn't recognize features of C++11 even after I specified the C++ version to be C++11 and then re-parsed my code.

My code, which replies on C++11 features such as `unordered_map` are compiling and running just fine though.

Hence, I hypothesized that I might not be telling code assistance to seek the right directories for various headers. Hence, I went to Tools -> Options -> c/C++ and added some more directories in the "Include Directories" section (for 4.7.2):

[image]

Strangely, next to the directories I just added are little keys. What do these little keys mean?

Fyi, code assistance still does not recognize C++11 features.

Comment: Just guessing: `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7.2` is a symlink that points to `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7` and the key simply means that this path followed a symlink and is not a 'real' path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are almost certainly the include paths built into the compiler. The code assistant needs to know them or it will miss vital information needed for understanding the other headers and completions but because they are built into the compiler they cannot be changed by the user so they have a key next to them to show they cannot be changed

This is however an educated guess based on my work in *other* C++ IDEs and knowledge of how compilers handle this stuff

Assuming you are using gcc you can find a list of the built in include directories with `echo | g++ -Wp,-v -x c++ - -fsyntax-only` and check if they match up.